# How to limit CPU usage in a while loop

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, limit, cpu-usage

How do you limit the CPU of a while loop?

In this case, the code which is inside the while loop:

```
Private Sub wait(ByVal time)
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()
        Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < time And StillOpen = True
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        sw.Stop()
    End Sub
```

But now, here is the issue. This loop is allowing the while loop to run every second, once a second, and the `wait` sub is causing this delay, as it should.

How can I limit the CPU that this is taking up? For some reason, my task manager says it is taking 50 CPUs to run this simple task, yet it should probably take no more than 1 or 2. Though the manager says it is taking that much CPU, my computer speed is not being affected at all, which is odd considering it is a two-year-old laptop.

I don't want any users to freak out about it, but knowing how people are these days....

Anyway, the language is vb.net. Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, that code is not inside the while loop itself, but a call for the subroutine is, i.e. `wait(1000)`

Comment: Refactor.  Seriously, there are way better constructs out there: waithandles, callbacks, etc.

Comment: What is the context this code is being used in?

Comment: while i < 100000000000 
wait(1000)
Run()
End While

Comment: And insert linebreaks where they ought to go ;)

Comment: @Cyclone: that "while i < 100000..." block is a very unusual, non-idiomatic construct. Why are you doing that? What behavior are you trying to achieve?  Knowing that, there's probably a better overall design we can suggest.

Comment: I am trying to loop forever, quite simply. What would you suggest I do? I understand it is a dumb way to handle it, but it actually works quite well.

Comment: Is this a rich application with a GUI?  The standard technique is to use Windows' event loop, and respond to events as the user generates them.  I was actually looking for more detail on what your application actually **does** ("update enemy sprites every second; respond immediately if the user presses a key") than **how** it does it ("loop forever").  Almost every interactive program out there loops forever.

Comment: I would hardly call it rich lol. In fact, its premise is based upon the fact that there is NO user interaction with the primary event, at all. The user can control how it appears to them, but they cannot control it. It is based off the popular browsergame "IdleRPG", except, without the rpg part kinda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a timer event !!! Nearly no cpu effort.

Comment: How can i change my stopwatch into a timer?

Comment: Correction: How can I measure the elapsed milliseconds on the timer?

Answer (score 6):

You could always perform some kind of sleep between iterations of the loop...

I'm not familiar with VB.NET but a duration of 100-200ms will probably be more than enough to drop the CPU usage.

Eg:

```
Do while (...)
    Application.blah();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
End
```

**Edit** After some research,  I think the function you want is: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()

Comment: Err, it actually has to wait for one second, else it will not function. It is a game, you see.

Comment: Right, but if you sleep for 100ms inside the loop that occurs 1000ms, you essentially end up just processing application events 10 times a second (or at whatever frequency you want), thus ensuring responsiveness.

Comment: Name "Sleep" is not declared.

Comment: Updated with the proper function.

Comment: If you're trying to block some work from happening and keep your UI responsive, you may need to look into other techniques, and like Joel suggested, refactor. This is just a hotfix to keep a loop from consuming all your CPU time, not a more advanced fix to cover parallel tasks (UI stuff and work). There are better answers to this question that will help you more.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is executing Application.DoEvents() constantly in the while loop, for the time duration specified in your `time` parameter.  This will consume one core of your CPU, which is why you're seeing 50% processor usage (you have a dual-core processor, correct?).  This is an ugly way to wait.  You could instead call Thread.Sleep(), passing it the number of milliseconds you'd like your thread to wait.

If you'd like your application to stay responsive, you might also spin off a timer, and block the UI from any action until the timer triggers.  Something like (lightly tested):

```
// constructor or designer code
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);

void Wait(int interval)
{
    timer.Interval = interval;
    timer.Start();
    BlockUIOperations(); // implement yourself
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();   
    EnableUIOperations(); // implement yourself
}
```

Here's my attempt at a translation into VB:

```
'' Add a Timer object to the form named "Timer".
'' Hook its Tick event to Timer_Tick

Private Sub Wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
    Timer.Interval = interval
    Timer.Start()
    BlockUIOperations() '' implement yourself
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    Timer.Stop()
    EnableUIOperations() '' implement yourself
End Sub
```

Comment: And yeah,dual-core processor.

Comment: See my code for a timer-based implementation that keeps the UI updated.

Comment: That isn't working, it just generated no less than 10 syntax errors.

Comment: @Cyclone: Such as?  I'm guessing some of those come from BlockUIOperations and EnableUIOperations, which you'll need to implement, of course.

Comment: Well, I tried it inside of my sub as a substitute, it said some things were undeclared and it also "got mad" because of the semicolons.

Comment: My code is C#.  You can translate it yourself, or try the VB I added to my answer.  You should do more than just copy and paste it, though.  Walk through it, understand what it does, and implement the UI operation functions if needed.

Comment: I do not see where timer_tick should be called.

Comment: @Cyclone: the comment at the head of the code discusses that.  Hook the Timer's Tick event to Timer_Tick, in the form designer or by hand.

Comment: Done, i missed the Handles section of that line lol. Anyway, it did not work unfortunately, as the application started it promptly froze, yet I executed the code correctly I believe.

Comment: Then just read up on Timers and add the code yourself.  It's a good thing to know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the CPU is always running at 100% when it's running, so the only practical way to limit the CPU usage is to run bursts or loop and sleeping in between.

Laptop CPUs usually have some SpeedStep technology or equievalent that will slow down the CPU when it's not working hard, but it's not reasonable to assume that your application would have access to control that, at least not directly. You might be able to affect it indirectly by measuring the CPU usage and adjust the length of the work and sleep cycles to get the desired result.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you don't think is correct, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Because I think CPU has nothing to do here. One needs to use interrupts, which do not measurably impact CPU, and that's done through events, in this case a Timer event.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind blocking the current thread, you could use a WaitHandle.

```
    Public Sub Wait(ByVal ms As Integer)

        Using wh As New ManualResetEvent(False)
            wh.WaitOne(ms)
        End Using

    End Sub

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Wait(5000)
        Console.WriteLine("Good-Bye!")

    End Sub
```

Of course, something more complex can be constructed depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sure, so long as it will resume the thread and update the UI, that is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect as a VB.net sleep replacement.  Now my console app is NOT reported as non responsive since I have no sleep commands!

Just add Imports System.Threading above your module and place this just above your sub main

```
Public Sub Wait(ByVal ms As Integer)

   Using wh As New ManualResetEvent(False)
        wh.WaitOne(ms)

    End Using
End Sub
```

Then, in your sub main, use

```
wait(100)
```

to pause your app for 100 miliseconds.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

You should take note of if you are doing this in the main UI Thread or a thread you have spun off.

For Threads the easiest way is to just Thread.Sleep(x miliseconds)

On the main UI thread I tend to use a DoEvents function in vb.net and vb6  like this

```
Public Sub TimeKiller(byval secondstowait as integer)
     dim tmptime as datetime = datetime.now

     do while datetime.now < dateadd("s",secondstowait,tmptime)
          Application.Doevents
     end while
End Sub
```

On the question of CPU usage I look at it like this.... if you make just a hard loop that like

```
while true
end while
```

I would expect to see very high cpu usage over 50% because the UI thread is hard blocking on this.... in most cases the windows system will limit the cpu usage of any given program so that its threads dont block the entire system.

The DoEvents ensure that windows message pumps fire correct and respond to correct.   It also ensures that the garbage collector fires on time.

Also if you have other threads spun up off of your UI.Thread your UI.Thread can respond to events fired from these other threads....

In such cases where your calling form controls from other threads and do form.InvokeRequired routines will be able to respond correctly.

Also The only time you should be hard looping on the MainUI thread is when it is in response to some user activity and you need to put waits in for the user to see progress of something....

If it is some kind of automated process that is always running... look to moving it to another thread.

Or if its something that runs periodically on a timer or a time that kicks off a thread.

Somebody please tell me if I am wrong on these assumptions....

Not sure about the Using wh As New ManualResetEvent(False)  wh.WaitOne(ms) as I have never heard of that and have no idea what that does.